# Mereology vs Epistemic Primacy

Tags: mereology

I'm having a very hard time understanding these two concepts and would love a comparison between the two. For context, I am not a philosophy major and am taking a class named philosophy and science.

Comment: i'm not going to downvote, but feel like you need more context -- what you already know -- than just stating what classes you're taking.

Comment: Please give some context on where you encountered those words, link the source, and ideally include a quote. They do not name similar things in the same category, so "comparison between the two" does not make much sense.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).